# Cache Static Tables Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

Using MYSQL, with EF 5.x and MVC3. I have a table with around 3.2 million rows which has city, country combo. I have a autocomplete textbox on the client side that takes city's search term and sends back suggestions using jQuery/ajax.

The challenge that I am facing is that I cache this table into my memory when its used for first time using:

```
        CityData = DataContext.Citys.OrderBy(v => v.Country).ToList();

        if (CityData.Any())
        {
            // Put this data into the cache for 30 minutes
            Cache.Set("Citys", CityData, 30);
        }
```

This timeouts even when I set my db-context timeout to 5 mins. When I run this SQL against the DB using MySQL client it takes about 3 min to pull all the rows.

What is the best way to read this data into cache or should I be doing something different?
Can I cache the table directly into MySQL cache memory if so how? Or should I be sending the term search directly to DB instead of doing it using data in cache.

Comment: If it is for autocomplete, wouldn't you have a query that uses the search term and only fetches relevant results? Or is that you want the search query to run off the cached data?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev makes a good point, youd probably be better off caching individual queries to the database. You can cache the query for a long period of time so after a while a large percentage of your searches will not be going to the database. You also have the option of caching the resultant json as a file, that way you just return the json file as soon as you get such a request.

Comment: yes the search term goes against the cached data

Comment: Was there a problem searching the actual table for your search term so that a cached version was necessary? Is the table indexed? If your query in the SQL client takes 3 min... that's a little troubling.

Comment: Hi @Justin Homes. Please check this tutorial:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx

Comment: its faster to do using cached data that going to DB that why using cache

Comment: I don't think a cache is necessary. A simple DB query like that would take 1ms or so. Not worth optimizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreeing with the comments to your question I would also suggest, with that many rows, you are likely limiting the returns on your auto-complete? (i.e. taking the top 10). The round trip to the DB for this should not be a major bottleneck unless you are trying to return all the results on each keystroke.

If it is a bottleneck, I might look to solve this by making an asynchronous call to the DB on each keystroke while continuing to filter the results you have already pulled locally. I think you will get faster results re-sorting your list in the DB and re-querying than the performance hit of trying to do this in code anyway - if I am understanding you intent / question correctly.

Caveat: I have not yet been in the position where a generic round trip to the DB approach has not been quick enough for my needs / volume of data in an auto-complete - someone else who has had to address performance issues here might be able to provide additional insight - any Google Engineers reading? :)

Comment: One more thought - I would be somewhat wary of trying to address performance issues that you anticipate having before they actually are an issue. From personal experience I have wasted a lot of time trying to write *clever* code to address problems I don't end up having anyway.

Comment: That's because you addressed them when you wrote the clever code :)

Comment: I am tempted to believe that... but it would only be encouraging more bad behaviour :)